# Data Converted to BigInt contains Decimal with E Proceeding with Plus sign

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i am using "SQL Server 2008 R2". I had a table that had a column Name `TimeSpent varchar(250)`. I am storing some Positive integer values in it . I am using `cast(TimeSpent as BigInt)` To insert data into this table. Some data after insertion get converted into decimal proceeding with 'e+' some values. For example 1.27923e+006,1.30313e+006.

Please suggest me what datatype i use resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets stored as 1.27923e+006 because

- It is a varchar column: You are not storing it as a number
- Your source value is a float

Your CAST is irrelevant here

Example:

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (Id int, Wrong varchar (250), Correct bigint);
DECLARE @bignumber bigint = 12345678901234567;
DECLARE @bignumber2 float = 12345678901234567;
DECLARE @bignumber3 varchar(250) = '12345678901234567';

SELECT @bignumber;

INSERT @foo VALUES (1, @bignumber, @bignumber);
INSERT @foo VALUES (2, @bignumber2, @bignumber2);
INSERT @foo VALUES (3, CAST(@bignumber2 AS bigint), CAST(@bignumber2 AS bigint));
INSERT @foo VALUES (4, @bignumber3, @bignumber3);
INSERT @foo VALUES (5, CAST(@bignumber3 AS bigint), CAST(@bignumber3 AS bigint));

SELECT * FROM @foo;
```

The E notation appears only where you insert float into varchar (case 3)
As an added bonus, float only capture 15 significant figures so you'll lose precision. This is even worse with a number like 1000000000123456789

Comment: Nice explanation with example.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation. I fixed it with reference of your example.